# Block Specific Words with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm still learning about Regular expressions, still little bit confused using it.

My case :
I need block some specific word in input html with javascript or jquery.

Words i need to block is admin or administrator keyword, i don't want people using keyword like admin or administrator when create new account (username).

I need to block keywords like admin, 4dmin, adm1n, 4dm1n or even ADMIN, 4Dm1N..No matter user input in lowercase or uppercase or even numeric to replace letter "A" with numeric "4".

For now my code is :

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputUser");
input.onkeyup = function() {
    input.value = input.value = input.value.replace(/(admin|4dmin|adm1n|4dm1n)/,"");
}
```

Please help dear masters, i'm stuck at this moment, any help i very appreciate.

Comment: You should be blocking these on the backend.

Comment: Blocking them on the front end does not **at all* prevent any moderately smart programmer from sending it to your server.

Comment: thank you masters for your suggestion, but i am totally new in php and javascript programming. is there a php code for the same answer in this question sir?

Comment: But he may want to block it on the frontend anyway so the user gets a proper error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a regular expression without bars more easily by using character classes and the `i` flag (ignores casing):

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/[a4]dm[i1]n/ig, '');
```

Make sure to only use a single `=` - your current code duplicates `input.value = input.value =`.

But do keep in mind that you shouldn't be relying on Javascript alone to manage this - also verify the input before putting it in the database.

Comment: thanks master for your quick answer, i'm very appreciate this.
work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using regex

```
^(?!.*admin|.*4dmin|.*4dm1n).*$
```

Comment: thanks master for your answer, i'm very appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an array of blacklisted words and onkeyup check if the `value` matches with any word in that array

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inputUser");
var restrictedVal = ["admin", "4dmin", "adm1n", "4dm1n"]
input.onkeyup = function() {
  if (restrictedVal.indexOf(input.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    input.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputUser">
```

Comment: thanks master for your answer, i'm very appreciate this :)